# When parsing json data i get: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

My code is the following

```
import json
import requests


def find_Price():
    r = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/Markets/GetMarketSummaries').text
    data = json.loads(r)
    for item in data['result']['MarketCurrency']:
        print(item)

find_Price()
```

When i try and parse the data from https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/Markets/GetMarketSummaries i get the error shown in the title, any clues as to the reason why?

Comment: That is likely because `data['result']` does not give a dictionary, but a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the data structure carefully. `data['result']` returns a list, where each item is a dictionary, but even in that dictionary, there isn't a key called `'MarketCurrency'`. Rather, you need to access the dictionary indexed by `'Market'`, and THAT has a key called `'MarketCurrency'`.

Hence, you need:

```
def find_Price():
    r = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/Markets/GetMarketSummaries').text
    data = json.loads(r)
    for item in data['result']:
        print(item['Market']['MarketCurrency'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can just use `r.json()`. I've used `re` here due to `pdb` purposes:

```
(Pdb) re.json()['result'][0].keys()
dict_keys(['Market', 'Summary', 'IsVerified'])
(Pdb) re.json()['result'][0]['Market']
{'MarketCurrency': 'BTC', 'BaseCurrency': 'BITCNY', 'MarketCurrencyLong': 'Bitcoin', 'BaseCurrencyLong': 'BitCNY', 'MinTradeSize': 1e-08, 'MarketName': 'BITCNY-BTC', 'IsActive': True, 'Created': '2015-12-11T06:31:40.653', 'Notice': 'This market is being delisted on August 25th, 2017.  ', 'IsSponsored': None, 'LogoUrl': None}
```

As you can see `result` is a list. Also `MarketSummary` isn't one of the keys, however `Market` is. Maybe that's what you were looking for?